# CRS does not match after upgrade to QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

QGIS project, which was saved in 2.0 has defined CRS for project as a whole and for each of the layers.

When I open the project in QGIS 2.2 and higher, one of the layers is shifted and does not match the rest of the project.

Changing CRS of that layer does not help and neither does exporting the layer in certain CRS and importing it again.

list of CRS:

- project: EPSG 3857
- shifted layer: EPSG 4326
- the rest of the layers: EPSG 5221

Comment: Have you tried enabling/disabling the **on-the-fly reprojection** option from _Settings > Options > CRS_?

Comment: Yes, I did. The layer is "shifted" just a few metres from where it should be (disabling otf reprojection moves it accross the globe)

Comment: Was the data captured in QGIS 2.0?

Comment: What do you mean by captured?

Comment: Who created the data and using what?

Comment: There are two sources. One set of data was created by third party and imported (cadastral parcel). On top of that, new layer was created by hand. This new, hand-made layer is shifted when imported into newer version of QGIS

Comment: So to clarify, you had a layer in EPSG 5221, from which you copied/traced into EPSG 4326, and now you are displaying in EPSG 3857. The original EPSG 5221 data looks fine, but the copied/traced EPSG 4326 is off?

Comment: I just inherited the data and the problem, but I think what you say is correct

Comment: Does the shift remain if you set the **Project** CRS to EPSG:5211?

Comment: yes, and also if I export the data in any CRS, the shift remains after loading the exported layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some inconsitency about the datum shift parameters for EPSG:5221.

Using gdalsrsinfo epsg:5221, GDAL 1.11.2 reports:

```
+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=42.5 +alpha=30.28813972222222 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=589,76,480,0,0,0,0 +pm=ferro +units=m +no_defs
```

Whereas the current QGIS 2.8.2 has this definition:

```
+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=42.5 +alpha=30.28813972222222 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=542.5,89.2,456.9,5.517,2.275,5.516,6.96 +pm=ferro +units=m +no_defs
```

The `towgs84` parameters are different (3-parms vs 7-parms). I'm not sure which one is more accurate, and if and when parameters changed in QGIS.

If you have still access to QGIS 2.0, look up the parameters there. You can set up a custom CRS in your running QGIS and assign it to the Krovak projected files.

Alternatively, you can save the WGS84 layer in QGIS 2.0 into Krovak projection, take it into QGIS 2.2, and save it back to WGS84 there. BTW, I suggest to update to QGIS 2.8.3. There are lots of bugs fixed since QGIS 2.2.

This bug report might be related: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9760 and there was a patch in http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-commit/2013-June/010976.html. The quoted source for the parameters has moved to http://freegis.fsv.cvut.cz/gwiki/S-JTSK_/_%C4%8Ceskoslovensk%C3%BD_transforma%C4%8Dn%C3%AD_kl%C3%AD%C4%8D.

The site offers different shift parameters for the Czech Republic, Slovakia, and the whole former Czechoslovakia. The values now used by QGIS are for the last one, while GDAL still uses the 3-parms set up by NIMA when WGS84 was established.

Comment: Perfect - after creating custom CRS with new parameters, the data align perfectly

Comment: The second CRS likely has a more accurate transformation statement: as you said 9 parameters vs 3 parameters. Since the data was captured from a different CRS using the 3 parameter transformation the data will not be as accurate as it would be using the current CRS 9 parameter transformation. There was a similar issue with British National Grid when migrating between GDAL versions. To fix this you might want to try: Open the file in QGIS 2.0, save the data as EPSG 5221, open the newly created layer in QGIS 2.2+ and reproject it back to EPSG 4326.